# Angular 2 CanActivate does not work

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I'm trying to create route guard, read a few blogs and [Angular 2 official documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/CanActivate-interface.html) on it. But I still can't make it work.

Here's RouteGuard (I've removed logging logic to be sure that problem is in routing, not in authentication logic.):

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate, CanActivateChild, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class RouteGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor() {
    var a = 5;
    console.log("RouterGuard called");
  }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    console.log("RouterGuard called");
    return true;
  }
}
```

Here i have some routes:

```
import { RouteGuard } from './common/routeGuard';
import { ClassifiersComponent } from './components/classifiers/classifiers.component';
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'classifiers', component: ClassifiersComponent, canActivate: [RouteGuard] },
];
```

And then i pass them in bootstrapper method:

```
import { RouteGuard } from './app/common/routeGuard';
import { ClassifiersComponent } from './app/components/classifiers/classifiers.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './app/components/home/home.component';
import { routes } from './app/app.routes';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
    ],
    providers: [
        { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy },
        { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' },
        RouteGuard
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        ClassifiersComponent
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I'm not sure what is wrong with this all, may be I'm missing something important. From debugging I can tell that it's hitting canActivate() breakpoint, but does not execute console.log, same goes for constructor.

**EDIT:** 
Other routes where there is not any route authentication works fine.

**EDIT2:**
I'm using 
  angular/core 2.2.0, 
  angular/router 3.2.0

Comment: What is the current behavior? What is the expected behavior?

Comment: Currently it blocks route? I'm not sure because it doesn't write in console anything. It should be writing that RouteGuard is called. And rout should not be blocked because canActivate() always returns true;

Comment: So  `RouterGuard called` is **not** being printed to the browser console?

Comment: `{ path: '', component: HomeComponent },` should be `{ path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },` if an empty path route doesn't have child routes.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer exactly.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer adding "pathMatch: 'full'" doesn't change anything.

Comment: Out of ideas. Are you using that latest version of Angular2 and the router?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer updated post with used versions

Comment: No idea. Can you reproduce in a Plunker? Plunker has an Angular2 TS template

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Update to angular/core 2.**3**.0, angular/router 3.**3**.0 solved this issue, I have no idea why.